# My app crashed everytime I send notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification from FCM to my device, but my app always stopped working every time I send a notification. What could be the problem?

Here's some of my code

```
// app-level build.gradle
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
}
```

// project-level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore:
  firebase_core: 
  firebase_messaging: 
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
```

error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.maztur.hunafa-z3QygagDkOlt4fQ6fzLBgw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.maztur.hunafa-z3QygagDkOlt4fQ6fzLBgw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.maztur.hunafa-z3QygagDkOlt4fQ6fzLBgw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3737)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1801)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.maztur.hunafa-z3QygagDkOlt4fQ6fzLBgw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.maztur.hunafa-z3QygagDkOlt4fQ6fzLBgw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.maztur.hunafa-z3QygagDkOlt4fQ6fzLBgw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3732)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    ... 8 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService;
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        ... 14 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com.google.firebase.iid.zzb extended by class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService' appears in /data/app/com.maztur.hunafa-z3QygagDkOlt4fQ6fzLBgw==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime(17164):        ... 14 more
I/Process (17164): Sending signal. PID: 17164 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely because you are adding both the Flutter Firebase dependencies as well as the native ones. You are not meant to add the native dependencies, as they will be added by the Flutter dependencies.

Try again after removing firebase-core, firebase-messaging and the design support dependencies from build.gradle.

Comment: Okay, thank you, that works. But I need to point out that I have to create a new project for this to works, If I just change the code on this project, it causes an error.

Comment: What versions do you use for the Flutter dependencies `cloud_firestore`, `firebase_core` and `firebase_messaging`? Your code above does not include the versions

Comment: I left it empty like that

Comment: I didn't even know that's possible - I did a bit of searching and it turns out leaving it empty means version 'any', as in any version, which could explain why you are getting those errors. Those packages depend on each other and you therefore cannot use random versions. Go to https://pub.dev/ and get the latest version for each of those packages.

Comment: Now that fixes the problem. Thank you so much for your help. When I left the version empty, I assumed it'll always get the latest package. I didn't know It'll get a random version.